# ¿Por qué no funciona el .catch?

Tags: firebase

Tengo una consulta a Firebase que es para un simple login, la cuestión es que por alguna razón cuando ingreso el usuario o la contraseña mal, en lugar de entrar en el `catch` no hace nada y se queda como esperando una respuesta.

¿Alguna idea de qué puede estar pasando?

```
db.collection('users').where('username', '==', req.params.username).where('password', '==', req.params.password).where('admin', '==', true).get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            res.json(doc.data());
        });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log('Error getting documents');
    });
};
```

Comment: El `.catch` se va a activar cuando ocurra una excepción, un evento no controlado. En este caso si el usuario y contraseña no son válidos va a entrar el `snapshot` y ahí es donde debes manejar el inicio de sesión o login ;)

Comment: Tampoco devuelve nada en doc

Comment: En donde se supone que deberia handlear eso?

Comment: ¿Desde dónde disparas el evento? Si es a través de un navegador igual y puedes revisar la consola pulsando la tecla `F12` para revisar si existe algún error al tratar de ejecutar tu query.

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado la solución:

```
db.collection('users').where('username', '==', req.params.username).where('password', '==', req.params.password).where('admin', '==', true).get()
  .then(function(querySnapshot) {
    if (querySnapshot.size > 0) {
      // Contents of first document
      console.log(querySnapshot.docs[0].data());
    } else {
      console.log("No such document!");
    }
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting document: ", error);
});
```